# Do I need a separate hosting plan for each domain if I want the sites responsive?

Tags: website, domain, web-development, web-hosting

I have a few new domains that I want to reserve.  When a user goes to any of those URLs I want the action to, somehow, redirect the user to a primary site that I already have a hosting plan for.  And I'll want a counter on the page of each ancillary domain as well.

So, in order to run hit-counter scripts on those satellites, do I need to buy a web hosting plan for each individual one?  What if I simply want them all to redirect to my primary site--do I still need an individual hosting plan for each?

Must a server script be engaged for a URL redirection?  How is that mechanism handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`When a user goes to any of those URLs I want a script to respond to the action by redirecting the user to a primary site that I already have a hosting plan for.`

If you get a hosting service like hostgator (not trying to drop names, but this is what I use), you can setup/buy a baby server, which allows you to use as many domain names on 1 hosting server as you please, as long as they are not for reselling purposes. They have a interface section that literally allows you to point the domain you have to any other domain on that list, without you needing to write any code yourself. I'm 100% sure there are other companies that have these services, but i don't know any off the top of my head.

`And I'll want a counter on the page of each ancillary domain as well.`

In the cpanel, you'll see a hit counter that shows you what each domain is getting hits wise, and fancy graphs and stats you'll.

This can also be done Without using the hosting companies interface with javascript or php when the client comes to Domain-x, or Domain-y (which are the redirect sites), your script will push them to domain-z automatically, and you can install hit counters before the redirect.

That being said, these pieces of code are all over the place, and is actually off topic in super user, you might want to try [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) instead.

I personally don't see a reason in getting a count in the re-directed domain when you're main focus  is to see how many hits you get on your primary domain, (my 2 cents)

Comment: Thank you.  Very helpful.  Question:  What do you mean by "...as long as they are not for reselling services."?  Because this is intended to be used to redirect potential clients that land on these domains to a business.

Comment: Lets say for example, you're a web designer, and you buy 10 domain names and point them all to your baby hosting plan and build website for 10 clients and host them all on the same server, and charge them for that service as if you're the hosting company, this is not allowed, which is in no way reflected on your setup, so you should be fine.